# ElasticSearch: how to combine two SearchResponse obj into one?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have two indexes, say A and B, with the following structure:

A contains among other things a field called `agent_key` like below:

```
        [...]
        "_source": {
                    "id": "1599048000PbsPVjP2bRWK",
                    "property_time": 1616637650000,
                    "property_key": "YO88AN0000027654869134276550001",
                    "**agent_key**": "50001000002765",
        [...]
```

B contains agents documents. It contains among other things the `agent_key` field like below:

```
     [...]
          },
            "upload_time": 1616637650000,
            "agent_key": "50001000002765",
     [...]
```

Using the Java high-level rest client it is easy to search each index separately. I have the use case where I need to return a SearchResponse that contains both, or rather the response from A should be enriched with the response from B.

How can I achieve that without reinventing the wheel? I am sure this is not a new use case.

Here my very poor attempt to try to find a solution: (it is pseudocode)

```
  public SearchResponse getEnhancedProperty() throws IOException {
        SearchResponse property = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        SearchResponse agent = getAgent(extractAgentKey(property)); 
        return combineResponses(property,agent); //<=== No idea how to combine responses
    }
```

Comment: got the feeling that the problem boils down to how to replace a json key-value within a json document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest including document B as a part of document A, in your search -

- first, you need to set ignore_unavailable to true in the query for A document, otherwise it will throw exception when it won't find doc b inside doc a.
- second, you can set document b, as a nested field in document a, and set "includeInParent" to true, so you can access B fields directly from A document.

lets call B - a document from index B, and same for A.

for the first part, an example would explain better:

```
NativeSearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(queryBuilder)
.withIndicesOptions(IndicesOptions.LENIENT_EXPAND_OPEN).build()
```

please note that I used the LENIENT_EXPAND_OPEN option, since it includes the ignore_unavailable option.

for the second part, you cant use the following field annotation:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true...)
```

then, you could set the B field inside A to the B search-result content:

```
A.setB(searchHit.getContent());
```